# Preflight OPTIONS request returns 403/forbidden and different headers in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, postman

I am currently developing a hybrid app which is also supposed to work in regular web-browsers via the official company domain later on. The backend provides a RESTful API, which support all kind of things: Getting entries, getting users, etc. The source of the request is, at least for testing and the app, not the domain itself but localhost.

What causes issues right now is posting using `POST`, `Content-Type: application/json` and a JSON body. When run in the browser for testing, Chrome performs a preflight OPTIONS request. I understand why, no issue with this. Unfortunately, the request always turns out to have a status of 403 - which, I think, das not correspond with the HTTP status but is more of an interpretation of chrome based on the response itself. Chrome also says that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is missing. Here are some facts that I could evaluate:

- The response in chrome does indeed not contain this and some other headers. Which makes absolutely no sense, because:
- The same OPTIONS request works fine with Postman (HTTP 200)
- The behavior of Chrome is identical in at least Firefox
- The response I get from Postman contains all the necessary headers:

The Postman-headers that come back from the OPTIONS request:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Auth-Token, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PATCH, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
```

Can someone help on what causes the preflight request in the browser to fail? Why does the OPTIONS response not contain the same headers in browsers and Postman? Let me know if you need further information! I didn't include code since the OPTIONS request is started by the browser and not by me anyway.

Thanks a lot in advance and best regards.

---

EDIT: Following are the complete requests from Chrome and Postman:

**Chrome:**

```
General:
Request URL: [HIDDEN]/api2/entries/57734/comments
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 403 
Remote Address: [HIDDEN]
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response:
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 20
Date: Tue, 24 Apr 2018 09:18:58 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.8.0
X-Application-Context: application:production
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Request:
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-DE;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: [HIDDEN]
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0; Pixel 2 Build/OPD3.170816.012) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

**Postman Headers:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Auth-Token, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PATCH, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Auth-Token
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1209600
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 24 Apr 2018 09:24:04 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Application-Context: application:production
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: "Unfortunately, the request always turns out to have a status of 403 - which, I think, das not correspond with the HTTP status but is more of an interpretation of chrome based on the response itself." — No. That will be the status it gets.

Comment: "Why does the OPTIONS response not contain the same headers in browsers and Postman?" — You've shared neither the complete defaults of the HTTP request not any of the code which generates the response.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I added the complete chrome request as far as I could find out from developer tools. The OPTIONS request itself is not writte by me, it is automatically generated by chrome, based on the original post request that is preflighted. I also added the postman response I get. As you can see, there is a difference in the response headers.

Comment: You still haven't included the request that Postman is sending or the code that generates the responses.

Comment: Did you figure out the issue? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score -2):

Browsers such as Chrome send http OPTIONS method before the real POST, PUT, … method you want to send. Then the OPTIONS method checks proper following origin, method and headers. You need to check the response headers of the OPTIONS method reuest, Access-Control-Allow-Origin/Headers/Method (I’m not sure.. exact headers name..) If you had 403 with OPTIONS method, you should check OPTIONS method allowance in your server! Or you need check your real request(POST, PUT, …) header method and headers whether those are corresponding with OPTIONS method response header such as Access-Control-Allow-*!!! Mostly it happend because of your custom headers! You need to add http OPTIONS response header, Access-Control-Allow-headers: your custom header name!

I hope it’ll help you